# No CSS qual é a diferença entre Pixel Density e Pixel Ratio? Como funciona as unidades como DPI, DPCM e DPPX

Tags: html5, css3, layout-responsivo, resolução-de-tela, ui

Com a "popularização" das [telas Retina](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tela_retina), principalmente em dispositivos Apple, tenho visto algumas pessoas usando media queries com medidas como:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { ... }
@media (min-resolution: 2dppx) { ... }
```

Mas ainda não consegui entender direito algumas coisas...

- Existe alguma diferença entre ***Pixel Density*** e ***Pixel Ratio***?
- Qual a diferença entre `DPI`, `DPCM` e `DPPX` como devo usa-las?

Reparei que no próprio DevTools existe uma opção para simular o `Device Pixel Ratio.` Porém não vi nada mudar na tela...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

**Pixel density** se refere a quantos pixeis cabem em determinado espaço fixo e é mais frequentemente informado como ppi (pixels por polegadas) ou dpi (pontos por polegada).
Usamos o termo **pixel ratio** quando você esta lidando com displays de alta densidade, ele serve para especificar como um pixel físico se compararia a um pixel de densidade 'normal' *(100ppi-200ppi)*

- **DPI**: Pontos por polegada
- **DPCM**: Pontos por centimetro
- **DPPX**: Pontos por pixel